# Scroll to queued divs on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I'm sure this is a pretty common question around here but after lots of research I can't seem to find an answer to my question.

So just a little warning; I'm really new into javascript and jQuery etc.

To the question! I'm trying to apply two images (It's img's that looks like buttons :P) which you click on and it scrolls to the "next" paragraph or div.

So to get an overview of how it looks, here' a part of the HTML:

```
<div id="scrollbuttons">
    <img id="prev" src="pics/prev.png"><a href="#"></a></img>
    <img id="next" src="pics/next.png"><a href="#"></a></img>
</div>
```

Also:

```
<div id="work">
    <p class="maintext">blabla</p>
</div>
<div id="gallery">
    <p class="maintext">blabla</p>
</div>
<div id="project">
    <p class="maintext">blabla</p>
</div>
<div id="finish">
    <p class="maintext">blabla</p>
</div>
```

So what I'm trying to create is when you click on "next", the page should smoothly and automatically scroll to firstly, "work", then to "gallery" etc.

And when you press "prev", the page should again smoothly and automatically scroll back to the previous point.

I have the latest jQuery version and I'd like to not install plugins if it's not absolutely needed.

So I hope this is enough info to get some help, I'd really appreciate it since I'm really new to JS.

Thanks in advance

/Emil Nilsson

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, this could probably be done a little more efficiently but it's dynamic and it works. Click the buttons to go forward and backward. FYI I added a mutual class called `section` to all of your content divs

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/E4s2v/)

```
var Section = "start";

$("#next").click(function(){

    if(Section == "start"){
       var nextSection ="work";
    }else{
        var nextSection = $("#"+Section).next(".section").attr("id");
    }

      $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: $("#"+nextSection).offset().top});
      Section = nextSection;
  });

$("#prev").click(function(){

   var nextSection = $("#"+Section).prev(".section").attr("id");

  $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: $("#"+nextSection).offset().top});
    Section = nextSection;
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need something like this

http://jsfiddle.net/urUFK/

the img would be inside of the anchor like this (semantics and W3C validation):

```
<a href="#"><img id="prev" src="pics/prev.png"></img></a>
```

on my version you just need to define the first element and the div id's